# Looking for simple habtm scope syntax in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a habtm relation :

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contact_types
end

class ContactTypes < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
end
```

and a contact_types_contacts table which relates them.

I'm trying to create a scope which selects contacts related with a specific ContactType. I have tried several syntaxes but not one worked.

For example

```
scope :suppliers,  -> { where(contact_types: 1) }
```

causes

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: contacts.contact_type_id:
>   SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE
>   "contacts"."contact_type_id" = 1  ORDER BY contacts.name asc LIMIT 20
>   OFFSET 0

Is there anyone to suggest me any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add join and to specify db column.

```
scope :suppliers,  -> { joins(:contact_types).where(contact_types: { id: 1}) }
```